# Cursor moved when window maximized and restored. Why, and how to prevent it?

Tags: c#, windows-console

Consider following sample:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleWindowTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the cursor to be in the first column of the line following "Press Enter to exit" text.

However if you run this example, maximize the console window and then restore it, it's not what happens. On each console window state change the cursor is moved further and further away, soon the text disappears as it's scrolled out of the view. This behavior is absurd. I tested it on Windows 10.

Is there a way around it without using `Win32 API`?
If the `Win32 API` is necessary, how to handle it most painless? I mean all windows are accessible through `hwnd`, but isn't the current console a sort of a special case? I think I could subscribe to some events of current console window but it seems a tedious task.

Comment: I can confirm that. Running example on Windows 10, maximizing/minimizing window several times will lead to that input cursor is shifted and prompt get very far away (you can scroll to it, but ...). Looks like a microsoft [bug](https://superuser.com/q/67131/547545) to me.

Comment: Works fine on my machine.  The console was changed heavily on Win10 to support the new Linux subsystem, might have something to do with it.  Technically you can call Console.SetBufferSize() to make the screen buffer size the same as Console.WindowWidth/Height.  No more scrollbar.  Rather heavy-handed for such a minor annoyance.

Comment: I see this in 10.0.14393. You can get the same behavior with a line of Python: `input('Press Enter to exit.\n')`. The problem goes away if the option to "Wrap text output on resize" is disabled. However, and this seems related, maximizing the window changes the window and buffer sizes. It increases the buffer size to the size of the maximized window, and then restoring the window doesn't restore the original buffer size and leaves the window size slightly smaller than what it was originally, by 1-3 cols/rows. Repeating this doesn't cause further changes.

Comment: @eryksun Wow, your workaround is better than mine with "Use legacy console" option checked :) This pretty much solves the problem.